# To show: Galois group of a polynomial is not an alternating group .

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, discriminant

I have a polynomial of this type: $p(t)+l(t)s(a,t)$ in $F_q(a)[t]$, where a=(a_0,...,a_m)$ are specialization.

I could show that this polynomial is doubly transitive, by making $a_0=0$ (specialization technique for irreducibility and assumptions on f and g).

Now I need to show that the discriminant of this polynomial is not a square. Here I do not know how to proceed. Could any one please help me

Comment: It may be my limitation and lack of exposure to specializations, but why couldn't you get an alternating group here? Say, if $p(t)$ is a cubic, irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_q$, and $\ell(t)=0$. Then the splitting field is $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}(a)$ and the Galois group is cyclic of order three, i.e. $A_3$. It is also easy make $A_2$ appear - make your polynomial a reducible quadratic. I know I'm nitpicking, but...

Comment: so your polynomial can be any polynomial in $\Bbb F_q(a)[t]$ ?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I thought  the polynomial $p(t)+l(t)s(a,t)$, is linear in $F(a,t)$. (By taking this polynomial as a polynomial in $a_0$,), hence irreducible,

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, the author further assumes p(t) and l(t) are relatively prime polynomials. and the doubly irreducibility is proved similarly

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, is there a general method to show the discriminant is not a square

Comment: Where does it say that the polynomial would be linear in $a_0$? You are leaving out an awful lot!